# Yii pass variable from controller to view not working

Tags: php, yii

I want to pass variable from controller to view but it doesn't working ...

**In Controller**

```
    class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function actionRegisterPage() 
    {
        // This function I have put it on url manager.
        // And I tried at here worked fine
        $util = new Utility();              
        $util->detectMobileBrowser();   
        $util->checkWebSiteLanguageInCookies(); 
        $this->layout = "masterLayout";
        $this->render('index');
    }
    public function actionSignIn(){

        if(blablabla){
            // Here is for me to display certain message, so I pass wish to pass $ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID to View
           $ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID = "ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID";

           $this->render('index',array('ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID'=>$ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID));
        }
    }

}
```

**In View**

```
<?php echo $ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID; ?>
```

**Error**

Undefined variable: ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID

Also tried declare in Controller `public $ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID = "ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID";` and `echo` in View ... still **Undefined variable: ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID**

Any Suggestion to do pass variable to view ? Thanks

Comment: I have tried your code it is working. I found this error "Use of undefined constant blablabla - assumed 'blablabla'".

Comment: @YatinMistry that blablabla i put for example only ... the problem is not there

Answer (score 1):

This trick worked

The value given in if condition is treated as constant variable. so if not worked 
So you have to add pass it as a string
blablabla to `"blablabla"`

Otherwise

`1==1` or any valid condition

```
public function actionSignIn(){

    if("blablabla"){   // Write value as string ("" in double quotes) other remove condition if not required

       $ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID = "ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID";

       $this->render('index',array('ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID'=>$ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID));
    }
}
```

---

Or Try like below

In Controller

```
public function actionSignIn(){

       $my_var = "My Custom Value";

       $this->render('index',array('my_var'=>$my_var));
    }
}
```

In view

```
echo $my_var;
```

Comment: check updated answer? and let me know above solution worked at your end?

Comment: blablabla is not the problem .... my problem is `$ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID ` no going to view

Comment: I have also tried it without if condition and it worked perfect. Not any issue or error.Otherwise more details to solve the issue.

Comment: I am not getting. Code is same as previous one. Have you tried with my function? Replace with my new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63986/discussion-between-yatin-mistry-and-the-smile).